# What is the best Schema.org type for service providers page?

Tags: schema.org

I'm looking for an appropriate Schema.org type for pages that will contain a list of service providers like a list of magicians.
The page will have their picture, name, phone and one line description.

I thought about [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness), but I’m not sure that it will match the page indent, and pretty sure that `LocalBusiness` is a better solution for a signal business page and not for list of providers.

Looking for a more suitable way to markup this pages and even good example.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Matching schema for page indent is not only about SEO - the page can be out of SE and still have schema markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each magician is a [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person), who may offer ([`makesOffer`](http://schema.org/makesOffer)) her/his service ([`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer)).

He may be a member of ([`memberOf`](http://schema.org/memberOf)) resp. work for ([`worksFor`](http://schema.org/worksFor)) resp. have an affiliation with ([`affiliation`](http://schema.org/affiliation)) an organization (e.g., a [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) or a [`PerformingGroup`](http://schema.org/PerformingGroup)).

Comment: Hi unor thanks for helping.
which of them will be the best match for list of providers, does there any schema markup for tables, or for comparison?

Comment: @MenasheAvramov: I don’t think there is a Schema.org type for comparisons. You could use [`Review`](http://schema.org/Review) if somone is reviewing their service. Also, there are types like [`Table`](http://schema.org/Table) and [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList), but they don’t add much semantic value.